Would Files.mismatch() work without a hitch on any file at all?
I found this Files.mismatch() method for comparing the raw byte-data of two files and checking that they are exactly equal, i.e., whether they are duplicate-files of each other.
Do you know whether there would be any problems using this method on very large files—in the order of gigabytes? and, does it work on all file-types? I'm confident that there would be no problems with-respect to these two points, but just to be sure.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class finding_duplicates {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        Path filePath1 = Path.of(/*[...]/Desktop/test1.[any extension you like]"*/);
        Path filePath2 = Path.of(/*[...]/Desktop/test2.[any extension you like]"*/);
       
        long mis_match = Files.mismatch(filePath1, filePath2);
       
        if (mis_match == -1){System.out.println("files are equal");}
        else{System.out.println("files are different");}
    }
}


Here is the source code of method mismatch from Eclipse temurin implementation of JDK 17. As you can see, it reads both files as streams of bytes, which means it can handle any type of file. Since the variable totalRead is a long, the method may not work correctly if the size of the file is greater than [constant] MAX_VALUE (in class java.lang.Long). Note that MAX_VALUE is more than nine exabytes so I don't think you need to worry about file size.
public static long mismatch(Path path, Path path2) throws IOException {
    if (isSameFile(path, path2)) {
        return -1;
    }
    byte[] buffer1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try (InputStream in1 = Files.newInputStream(path);
         InputStream in2 = Files.newInputStream(path2);) {
        long totalRead = 0;
        while (true) {
            int nRead1 = in1.readNBytes(buffer1, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            int nRead2 = in2.readNBytes(buffer2, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

            int i = Arrays.mismatch(buffer1, 0, nRead1, buffer2, 0, nRead2);
            if (i > -1) {
                return totalRead + i;
            }
            if (nRead1 < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                // we've reached the end of the files, but found no mismatch
                return -1;
            }
            totalRead += nRead1;
        }
    }
}


Could you explain in more detail why you think this function cannot handle Files larger than Long.MAX_VALUE correctly? Both files are read in chunks way smaller than Long.MAX_VALUE, so I don't see the problem.

@Sören the long might overflow, and report the mismatch in the wrong position, and it can even report -1 as the mismatch position, which would normally signal that there is no mismatch.

I guess that code you posted there does the same as my own except yours handles the rare case where the file-size is that extreme size you mentioned.


Do you know whether there would be any problems using this method on very large files - in the order of gigabytes?

Well one problem is that it would take a long time for mismatch to read and compare files that are in the order of gigabytes.
There is something you can do about this.  Since you just care if the files are different ... not where the differences are ... you can start by comparing the file's sizes.  If two files have different sizes, they will be different.  If your files are held on a file system (partition) that automatically generates and stores checksums in file metadata, then comparing checksums will be fast too.  The logic would be:
//
// pseudo-code ...
//
fs = ...    // the file system
if fs.length(f1) != fs.length(f2):
    // they differ
elif fs.storesChecksums &&     // depends on file system type!!
     fs.storedChecksum(f1) != fs.storedChecksum(f2):
    // they differ
elif Files.mismatch(fs, f1, f2) != -1:
    // they differ
else:
    // they are the same

In short, do the quick / cheap tests before a full byte-by-byte comparison.

Does it work on all file-types?

At the level that you are comparing these files, there is only one type: an array of bytes.  It works at this level.
However, if you were wanting to consider the semantics of the file content then this approach doesn't work.  For example, with simple text files, you might want to ignore difference in line termination sequences, white space at ends of lines when deciding if files are "exactly equal".  Obviously mismatch won't do that.

"Does it work on all file-types?" -- And just a general note since it seems the OP is testing for equal files: The mismatch method does not perform any kind of semantic analysis. If all you care about is finding exact duplicates, then mismatch may be an appropriate choice. But if you care about whether or not two files contain the same high-level information despite different bytes, then mismatch (and size checks) will report false negatives.

If this is a key domain problem with large files than it might be better to store them on a partition that has a file system that stores checksums in its metadata

Is it truly right to say that if two files have exactly the same size in bytes then they are certainly identical? Or rather that the odds of them then having different content are negligible?

"Is it truly right to say that if two files have exactly the same size in bytes then they are certainly identical?" Of course not!!  But if the two files have a different number of bytes they are NOT identical.  Please read the pseudo-code I added to the question in the last update.
